# Windows MapViewOfFile and Parallel Processing

Tags: c++, windows, memory-mapped-files

I am looking to process a binary file that has the following structure:

[Meta Data: Key1 : Offset1, Size1 | Key2 : Offset2, Size2,...][ Data related to Key 1 ][ Data Related to Key 2]
^ Offset1                ^Offset2

The size of each block can vary, the blocks that are processed each time can vary, and the treatment of the block can vary.
The overall function is approximately ProcessFile(File, KeyList, KeyOptions).

In pseuocode, the core loop will be along the lines of:

```
omp parallel for
    for Key in KeyList:
        - Retrieve Key Offset, KeySize
        - ProcessBlock(Block, KeyOptions[Key])
```

For maximum efficiency, and avoid reading the file all at once, I am using Memory Mapped Files on Windows. My question is the correct way to manage the blocks in the parallel for loop to minimise overhead.
The process for creating the MapViewOfFile is CreateFile -> CreateFileMapping -> CreateMapViewOfFile. What is the correct object to pass to ProcessBlock:

- The FileMapping and Offset/Size?
- A MapViewOfFile?